# change value of <meter> dynamically from $scope variable

Tags: angularjs, html

I am trying to use meter tag to show battery power indicator. It works with hard coded value but does not work with $scope variable.Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksp5bu15/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
 <div id="page-wrapper">
    <p>
      <meter min="0" max="4" low="1" high="3" optimum="4" value="2"></meter>
    </p>
    <p>
      <meter min="0" max="4" low="1" high="3" optimum="4" value="value"></meter>
    </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

**JS*

```
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("main", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.value = 2
}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use **`{{value}}`** to reflect the **scope value**.

So use,

**`value="{{value}}"`**

instead of

**in `value="value"`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<style>
.styled meter {
  /* Reset the default appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;

  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  
  /* For Firefox */
  background: #EEE;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

/* WebKit */
.styled meter::-webkit-meter-bar {
  background: #EEE;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2) inset;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.styled meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value,
.styled meter::-webkit-meter-suboptimum-value,
.styled meter::-webkit-meter-even-less-good-value {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.styled meter::-webkit-meter-optimum-value {
  background: #86CC00;
}

.styled meter::-webkit-meter-suboptimum-value {
  background: #FFDB1A;
}

.styled meter::-webkit-meter-even-less-good-value  {
  background: #CC4600;
}


/* Firefox */
.styled meter::-moz-meter-bar {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.styled meter:-moz-meter-optimum::-moz-meter-bar {
  background: #86CC00;
}

.styled meter:-moz-meter-sub-optimum::-moz-meter-bar {
  background: #FFDB1A;
}

.styled meter:-moz-meter-sub-sub-optimum::-moz-meter-bar {
  background: #CC4600;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  padding: 0.4rem 0.8em;
  background: #69c773;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #498b50;
  color: white;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 0.25rem;
  text-align: center;
}

button:hover, button:focus {
  opacity: 0.75;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 -3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
}

</style>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<div id="page-wrapper">
<p>
    <meter min="0" max="4" low="1" high="3" optimum="4" value="4"></meter>
  </p>
  <p>
    <meter min="0" max="4" low="1" high="3" optimum="4" value="{{value}}"></meter>
  </p>
 </div>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.value = 2
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**PLEASE RUN THE ABOVE SNIPPET**

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/H1Arg6slfJj51ZqUiTUo?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations as per your fiddle :**

- You forgot to include `AngularJS` library in your fiddle.
- To get the `$scope` value into the `HTML` . Use angular expression `{{value}}`
- Change `LOAD TYPE` to `No wrap - in <head>` from `onLoad` in `JAVASCRIPT` section of the fiddle.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ksp5bu15/2/)**